# Facebook plugin using iframe not working on website

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, plugins

somehow the events stopped showing up on the website using the iframe:

`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLimboLatino&tabs=events&width=500&height=490&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" width="500" height="490" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>`

we've checked the page settings but there are no restrictions set for age or countries (I read that as problem for other pages)

Any idea how to solve this? (this is not a wordpress site)
And I am not the owner the facebook site https://www.facebook.com/limbolatino

Do I need to create a developer ID or something with FB??

To check the site see: https://www.limbolatino.nl

Thanks, Lars

Comment: If you don't own the facebook page how do you then know if there are any country or age restrictions?

Comment: Cause I checked that with the customer who owns the website. And it worked before and he said he didn't change anything (which was correct as he sent me the screenshot showing that the settings are correct)

Comment: Facing same issue, did you fine any resolution or what was causing it

Comment: No, I still didn't find a solution. First this was not working for events for now neither for the timeline. It's a fb issue but I have nowhere seen a resolution yet. Only 3rd party software (paid) is stating that it works with their tool but I havent tried that.